# Dompurify converting "<" to "&lt;"

Tags: javascript, html, dompurify

I am using DOMPurify to sanitize my HTML content. Everything works fine, but when I use the characters `<` and `>`, it is being converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Eg: `We have <a>Tea</a> // Outputs: We have Tea`

Eg: `Use '<' and '>' to compare values // Outputs: Use '&lt;' and '&gt;' to compare values`

The issue is with second example. I want to show it as `<` instead of `%lt;`

So my only option is to perform a string replace after passing through DOMPurify to replace `&lt;` and `&gt;` with `<` and `>`. Is there any other option ?

Comment: If it's html, `&lt;` *does* show as `<`. What's the problem?

Comment: I am allowing only a set of html tags. Namely anchor tags, bold and underline tags. All other tags need to be removed. But I need to show these characters as it is. I need to display it in a textarea. But it is shown as `&lt;` inside textarea.

Comment: How are you putting the html in the text area?

Comment: Just like <textarea>renderValue()</textarea>. I am using React Js

Comment: Since it's html, and you want to display the text, you'd use `<textarea dangerouslySetInnerHTML={renderValue()} />`

Comment: Ah, this should work. The logic seems to work fine. Let me implement it and will update you. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had the similar situation, value of my fields such as `<img onload="alert('hacked') />` would turn to `<img>`, `<p> Testing </p>` would turn to `<p> Testing </p>` but `Test < Test2` would turn to `Test &lt; Test`.
Solution:
Take the value returned from Dompuriy and find `&lt; and &gt;` and replace them with `< and >`;
Beware, this solution may have some trade offs with the security.
Here is the function:

```js
export const convertHtmlEntityToAngleBrackets = (fieldText) => {
  const htmlEntities = /&(lt|gt);/
  const isHtmlEntityUsed = htmlEntities.test(fieldText)
  if (isHtmlEntityUsed) {
    return fieldText.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
  } else {
    return fieldText
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## dangerouslySetInnerHTML

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: renderValue() }} />`

(*credit: @Bergi*)